# Bibtex doesn't compile on MAC OS

Tags: bibtex, errors, mac

I am using Texstudio on MAC and I am trying to include some bibliography references in my thesis but bibtex refuses to compile. The pdf with all the figures is generated but all my references appear as "?" and I get the following error message:
Error: Could not start the command: /Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex "Thesis_test".aux

The bibtex compiling has worked in the past (2015) but I've only started re-using it recently and changed some configurations after the OS X El Capitan update.

I have tried to compile several times (with Latex+Bibtex+Latex+Latex) but nothing changes and the .bbl file isn't generated. The only files generated after compiling are .aux, .log, .pdf and .synctex.gz
I have tried uninstalling Texstudio and re-installing it. I have tried using a different compiler (Texmaker) and the problem persists so I'm assuming it's something wrong with my MAC configuration. Also, I have tried compiling the same files on a PC on Texstudio and it works perfectly fine (including bibliography).

Attached below is a screenshot of my texstudio configuration and I also copied a test file with the preamble I use for my thesis.

If you have any idea what can be wrong, that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

[image: Texstudio configuration]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},left=38mm,right=38mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\newcommand{\normallinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} \normalsize}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla as described in \cite{Janmey2011a}.

\bibliography{bibliotest}

\end{document}
```

and my bibliography file: bibliotest.bib

```
@article{Janmey2011a,
author = {Janmey, Paul A. and Miller, R. Tyler},
journal = {Journal of Cell Science},
number = {1},
pages = {9--18},
title = {{Mechanisms of mechanical signaling in development and disease.}},
volume = {124},
year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For me, it compiles fine. Did you run the `pdflatex-> bibtex -> pdflatex (×2)` cycle?

Comment: Yes I did try to run this cycle but whenever I try to run bibtex I get the same error message: 
Error: Could not start the command: /Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex "Thesis_test".aux
Could it be that the path for bibtex in my configuration is wrong? It seems to be the standard path for MAC users

Comment: do you have a bibtex executable in that directory?

Comment: I have no precise idea, as I'm not a Mac user. You can try to check the path for bibtex with  `kpsewhich`.

Comment: On my Mac, `bibtex` also has the path `/Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex`. Can you check if your file is there and also has size 191936?

Comment: Which version of MacTeX is installed on your system?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. My bibtex file wasn't in the directory mentioned above. Everything was in /Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin/bibtex %.aux 
I've now changed the bibtex path and it works!

Comment: The .bib file should either be in the same folder as the root .tex file or on ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib. Please run `which bibtex` in Terminal and see if bibtex is found. If not please run `echo $PATH` and let us know what it returns.

Comment: To confirm that your settings point to the correct directory: what do you see if you type      `ls /Library/TeX/texbin/` in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Please run the following, minimalist version of the example code you provided. Specifically, copy the entire code into a file called (say) `test.tex`; save the file and run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. If everything goes well, you should get the following output:

[image]

If you do *not* get this output, please report about all warning and error messages you're getting.

Here's the code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliotest.bib}
@article{Janmey2011a,
author  = {Janmey, Paul A. and Miller, R. Tyler},
journal = {Journal of Cell Science},
number  = {1},
pages   = {9--18},
title   = {Mechanisms of mechanical signaling in development and disease},
volume  = {124},
year    = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{Janmey2011a}
\bibliography{bibliotest}
\end{document}
```